# Redirect Users On Wrong Url

Tags: symfony

Is there a way to redirect the users to the homepage whenever the user enters a wrong url?

Let's say `app.php/Contact` triggers a 404 error and I would like all 404 errors to be redirected to the homepage?

I am pretty sure I read that somewhere at a time, but can't find it anymore. I think it was a else statement in the config file?

Comment: You shouldn't put every damn symfony tag you can find in all your questions. Just add the related one. For example, add [tag:symfony-2.0] **OR** [tag:symfony-2.1] depends on which version your are using **for your question**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should extend [ExceptionController](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Bundle/TwigBundle/Controller/ExceptionController.php#L26) and redefine `showAction()` with the logic you need.

Simply as:

```
if (404 === $exception->getStatusCode()) {
    //do your logic
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an .htaccess file and add the following line:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /home.php
```

Comment: Awesome! I'll give this a try. This is supposed to go on web/ folder right? Just wondering, does this work on dev mode as well or is there a way to inactivate it somehow? thanks

Comment: It can be inactivated only if you delete the code from .htaccess file.